# Django shared model instance with per user overrides

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django model that I want to centrally manage for my users. However, I also want users to be able to modify some fields for themselves, while allowing the central control to update the referenced model and have those updates appear for users (unless they have overriden this field).

For this example, let's make it a store page, where users have their own whitelabeled pages.

Items are created centrally, but each individual user can (optionally) edit the description and price for their own store.

Centrally managed item:

```
class StoreItem(models.Model):
    unit_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Item that a user has overriden:

```
class UserStoreItem(models.model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(StoreItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # I'd like these fields to be inherited from the item ForeignKey if not set
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("user", "item"),)
```

Is there a good way to do what I'm looking for? I've thought about just copying `StoreItem` for each user however that would lose the ability to be updated centrally.

Bonus points if I'm able to have `UserStoreItem` inherit `StoreItem`'s fields without having to define them twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data model as you've defined (I'd use the same given the requirements you've listed). You could read the data out as follows:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

user_store_items = UserStoreItem.objects.filter(
    user=user,
    item=OuterRef('id')
)
store.items.annotate(
    user_description=Subquery(user_store_items.values('description')[:1]),
    user_price=Subquery(user_store_items.values('description')[:1]),
).annotate(
    calc_description=Coalesce('user_description', 'description'),
    calc_price=Coalesce('user_price', 'price'),
)
```

This approach is probably only good for a handful of fields. If there are more than 2-5, I'd avoid this because the query is pretty ugly. In fact, you may want to try using [`extra`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra) to get the UserStoreItem row and do the above coalesce there.